# Maze-solving BFS algorithm not working, checks the same number a lot of times

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, breadth-first-search, maze

I am trying to create a maze-solving algorithm. I watched a few tutorials online, and have come across the BFS algorithm. I tried implementing it my self. This is what I wrote:

```
import queue, numpy, time
from PIL import Image

def maze(mazename, start=True, end=True):
    q = queue.Queue()
    img = Image.open(mazename)
    array = numpy.array(img).tolist()
    for x, y in enumerate(array):
        for i, h in enumerate(y):
            if h == 0:
                array[x][i] = (0, 0, 0)
            else:
                array[x][i] = (255, 255, 255)
    if start and end:
        for x, y in enumerate(array[0]):
            if y == (255, 255, 255):
                start = [x+1, 1]
        for x, y in enumerate(array[-1]):
            if y == (255, 255, 255):
                end = [x+1, len(array)]
    start[0] = start[0]-1
    start[1] = start[1]-1
    end[0] = end[0]-1
    end[1] = end[1]-1
    start = tuple(start)
    q.put("")
    while True:
        #Checking for end
        parse = q.get()
        m = list(start)
        for i in parse:
            if i == "D":
                m[1] = m[1]+1
            if i == "U":
                m[1] = m[1]-1
            if i == "L":
                m[0] = m[0]-1
            if i == "R":
                m[0] = m[0]+1
        print(m, end)
        if m == end:
            m = list(start)
            array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
            for i in parse:
                if i == "D":
                    m[1] = m[1]+1
                    array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                if i == "U":
                    m[1] = m[1]-1
                    array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                if i == "L":
                    m[0] = m[0]-1
                    array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                if i == "R":
                    m[0] = m[0]+1
                    array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
            return array
        #Find new trails
        directions = ["U", "D", "L", "R"]
        if m[0] == 0:
            directions.remove("L")
        elif array[m[1]][m[0]-1] == (0, 0, 0):
            directions.remove("L")
        if m[0]+1 == len(array[0]):
            directions.remove("R")
        elif array[m[1]][m[0]+1] == (0, 0, 0):
            directions.remove("R")
        if m[1] == 0:
            directions.remove('U')
        elif array[m[1]-1][m[0]] == (0, 0, 0):
            directions.remove('U')
        if m[1]+1 == len(array):
            directions.remove("D")
        elif array[m[1]+1][m[0]] == (0, 0, 0):
            directions.remove("D")
        for direction in directions:
            q.put(parse+direction)

t1 = time.time()
arr = maze(input("Enter maze file name: "))
print(time.time()-t1)
Image.fromarray(numpy.array(arr).astype(numpy.uint8)).show()
```

I tried it on this image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikepound/mazesolving/master/examples/tiny.png
It worked just fine. It took it between 3 and 7 seconds.

I then tried it on this image:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikepound/mazesolving/master/examples/normal.png

It has been running for the past 15 minutes, and it still hasn't passed the 10 row of the 40x40 image once. It checks the same numbers hundreds of times and I can't figure out why. Could someone point out the flaw in my algorithm and help me fix it? I've tried implementing a visited list, it just slows down the program. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a list for `visited`. You should keep track of where you have been so far in order not to repeat the same locations.

When you have a visited list you can use it to check to see if you have already been at that pixel before you make the move.

```
   def maze(mazename, start=True, end=True):
    q = queue.Queue()
    visited = []
    img = Image.open(mazename)
    array = numpy.array(img).tolist()
    for x, y in enumerate(array):
        for i, h in enumerate(y):
            if h == 0:
                array[x][i] = (0, 0, 0)
            else:
                array[x][i] = (255, 255, 255)
    if start and end:
        for x, y in enumerate(array[0]):
            if y == (255, 255, 255):
                start = [x+1, 1]
        for x, y in enumerate(array[-1]):
            if y == (255, 255, 255):
                end = [x+1, len(array)]
    start[0] = start[0]-1
    start[1] = start[1]-1
    end[0] = end[0]-1
    end[1] = end[1]-1
    start = tuple(start)
    q.put("")
    while True:
        #Checking for end
        parse = q.get()
        m = list(start)
        for i in parse:
            if i == "D":
                m[1] = m[1]+1
            if i == "U":
                m[1] = m[1]-1
            if i == "L":
                m[0] = m[0]-1
            if i == "R":
                m[0] = m[0]+1
        if m not in visited:
            visited.append(m)
            print(m, end)
            if m == end:
                m = list(start)
                array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                for i in parse:
                    if i == "D":
                        m[1] = m[1]+1
                        array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                    if i == "U":
                        m[1] = m[1]-1
                        array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                    if i == "L":
                        m[0] = m[0]-1
                        array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                    if i == "R":
                        m[0] = m[0]+1
                        array[m[1]][m[0]] = (255, 0, 0)
                return array
            #Find new trails
            directions = ["U", "D", "L", "R"]
            if m[0] == 0:
                directions.remove("L")
            elif array[m[1]][m[0]-1] == (0, 0, 0):
                directions.remove("L")
            if m[0]+1 == len(array[0]):
                directions.remove("R")
            elif array[m[1]][m[0]+1] == (0, 0, 0):
                directions.remove("R")
            if m[1] == 0:
                directions.remove('U')
            elif array[m[1]-1][m[0]] == (0, 0, 0):
                directions.remove('U')
            if m[1]+1 == len(array):
                directions.remove("D")
            elif array[m[1]+1][m[0]] == (0, 0, 0):
                directions.remove("D")
            for direction in directions:
                q.put(parse+direction)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of an implementation of this on my code?

Comment: @Serket I updated my answer. You will need something along those lines.